# Flex Box Items responsively but aligning to the right

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to use flex box in a responsive layout. For large screen sizes, I have been able to use flex. But for small screen sizes, without changing the layout, I would like it such that. 
1) Block 4 is on the utmost left
2) Block 2 is on the right of Block 4
3) Block 3 and 4 are aligned underneath Block 2. Such that Block 4 has nothing below it.

My markup is as such:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class ="greenbox" style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green BLOCK 1 with more content.</div>
  <div class ="bluebox" style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE BLOCK 2</div>  
<div class ="yellowbox" style="background-color:yellow;">yellow BLOCK 3</div> 
  <div class ="redbox" style="background-color:coral;">BLOCK 4 RED</div>
</div>
```

My css for starters is:

```
#main {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start

  align-items: center;
}

#main div {
padding: 10px;
}

.redbox {
order: -1;
}
```

Comment: you're missing a ; after flex-start

also, grid layout would make this easier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout - support is pretty much the same for grid as for flexbox: https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: *1) Block 4 is on the utmost left* – Is that correct? Where is Block 1?

Comment: Block 1 will be to the right of Block 4

Comment: Can you draw that? It doesn't make sense in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CSS-Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for your narrow viewports. I used [line-based placement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid) to position your boxes.

I am not really sure where you want to place your boxes. So here a code example with arbitrary positioning for now:

```css
.box {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box--green {
  background-color: #3D9970;
}

.box--blue {
  background-color: #0074D9;
}

.box--yellow {
  background-color: #FFDC00;
}

.box--red {
  background-color: #FF4136;
}

/* 
 * position your boxes wherever you want in your grid
 */

#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); /* 2 rows */
}

.box--1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

.box--2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 5;
}

.box--3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.box--4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5;
}

/* 
 * use flex positioning (and get rid of the grid) on bigger screens 
 */

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  #main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #main div {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .redbox {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

  <div class="box box--1 box--green">BLOCK 1 - with more content</div>
  <div class="box box--2 box--blue">BLOCK 2</div>
  <div class="box box--3 box--yellow">BLOCK 3</div>
  <div class="box box--4 box--red">BLOCK 4</div>

</main>
```

Comment: This looks quite good. I am not sure about Grid as it has less browser compatibility than Flexbox. But I really like how you laid it out and its easy to read.

Comment: Compatibility is quite good (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). It's all about IE11, but this shouldn't stop us. Google for fallbacks. It is easy to provide a decent layout with older techniques you are used to for older browsers – and then kick in with a grid for the newer ones. There are some nice tutorials out there for grid fallbacks. Rachel Andrew wrote some nice articles about that topic.

Comment: How would I extend Box 1 so the green color extends into the Row 2, and occupies column 1 and 2. Right now there is no color there? Is that possible to do?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible: Just change the value for end of row like this: **.box--1 {grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;}** In a grid, you can position your boxes whevever you want. See the links I added, about line-based placement. You just add where to start end where to end, for column and row. This link might help you: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Hi Thank you. This grid stuff is quite interesting. But now I have a trick followup question. How can I use "    grid-auto-columns: min-content". I only want that setting applied to Block 3. I want Block1, and Block 2 to not be fit to min content. When I set it like that on the parent, everything gets set to min content.

Comment: Well, like this: `grid-template-columns: auto auto min-content auto;`. A value for each of the four columns. Block 3 is on the third column. 
Read the documentation first and do some practice layouts. It takes some time. Grid is quite complex, but provides a lot of possibilities.
We shouldn't abuse the comment function. Feel free to post a new question. We should stick to the context of the question above.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First and for most cut out your styling code from html and put them in the css file. This is for the reason of using css file purpose and cleaner html file.

Back to your question

Strictly use `@media query` for your layout in your inner css to smoothly resize from larger to small screen vise versa.

Start your code by mobile-first philosophy design then choose a breaking point where you want you use for those `@media screens` and at last apply the a different design layout for each *"your screen need"* one of them.

For mobile-first design use this:

```
.block1 {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: flex-left;
     }

 .boxright2 {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: flex-right;
    }
  .block3 .block4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    Float: clear;
     }
```

Then use below code for breaking point and add or reduce the sizes of each item based on the viewport provided here:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
   //your code goes here for tablet
   }

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

//your code goes here for larger screen like desktop and laptop
}

P.S. play with them you will figure it out later.
```

Comment: Let me correct myself           use display: flex-start;          display:flex-end;            replace those display: flex-left and right properties with the above one then rest is your assignment